# How to set specific UITableViewCell separator position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My question is I want my table view cell's separator to begin from specific position. Here is a visualization of what I want:

[image]

While I was searching, I found some questions about how to start separator line from beginning of the cell and explanations were made saying giving custom insets. I supposed same should work for me and I tried giving custom insets from interface builder. However it did not work.

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i try and it work , in swift

```
    self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 35, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

in Objective C:

```
  self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 80, 0, 0);
```

Comment: In common sense, your answer is correct; but I really don't know why it still does not work for me. Is there any suggestion for that?

Comment: i think you should share your code, it 's easy for help

Comment: For confidential reasons, I cannot share. But still thanks for help.

Comment: I found where I messed up. I could not set my cell's borders properly. After I corrected, it worked like a charm. Thank you @Onik IV and main poster :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Interface Builder. In the Attributes Inspector look for indentation and set it to what ever you want.

[image]